# Acts-as-taggable-on displaying tags on the basis of most used tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, rubygems, acts-as-taggable-on

How to display tags in sorted order of usage. i have this code:

```
<% tag_cloud Question.tag_counts, %w[s m l] do |tag, css_class| %>
```

how to make amends to display it in sorted order of usage.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use their helper method for returning the most used tags and then sort that further if needed?

```
 ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.most_used(10) #10 is the limit of tags you want back, default is 20
```

Then you can further sort that if needed by doing something like:

```
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.most_used(10).order("created_at DESC")
```

Comment: i am able to use the above mentioned code(in question) and make a tag cloud,i want to display the most used tags in a window but could not figure out what method should i use to code it

Comment: You mean you have the results you need you just aren't sure how to display them in the view?